# How to perform JSON schema property validation based on enum value in another property

Tags: json, jsonschema

Based on the given JSON schema, If I have to build "required" for the 'DayActivity' based on the 'Day' selected in DayHeader (e.g Only PhysicalActivity should be required If Day is SUNDAY) , how do i build the JSON schema? I've tried various approaches such if then else and definitions. When I generate JSON file based on the JSON schema, it couldn't validate the required 'DayActivity' selected by the "Day" attribute. 
Basically how do I refer the value selected in other property and build "required"? Appreciate any reference for this issue.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "DayHeader": {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Day": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "SUNDAY",
            "MONDAY",
            "TUESDAY",
            "WEDNESDAY",
            "THURSDAY",
            "FRIDAY",
            "SATURDAY"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "day"
      ]
    },
    "ActivityDetail": {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "DayActivity": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "PhysicalActivity": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "Walking",
                  "Running"
                ]
              },
              "StudyActivity": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "Maths Class",
                  "Science Class"
                ]
              },
              "ArtActivity": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "Drawing",
                  "Dance"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example JSON instance where you’d expect the validation to fail? That’d make it a bit easier. Also: be careful with casing. You are defining two properties on the `DayHeader`: “Day” and “day” (via “required”). Is the `DayActivity` also “required” and with a “minItems” of 1 then? Just making the `PhysicalActivity` “required” seems to leave a lot of loopholes allowing to still omit it. Is that intentional or maybe the reason why you don’t get the results you’re looking for. `if`/`then` sound like the right approach. Maybe include your attempt here as well.

Comment: You do not need to (and should not) redefine `$schema` at any level other than the root of the schema.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON Schema - conditional validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424330/json-schema-conditional-validation)

Comment: @Carsten DayActivity needs to have minItems as 1.

Comment: @Relequestual Thanks for Sharing. I will try it out and update this thread.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38781027/5127499) seems more comprehensive as it doesn't only focus on `if`/`then`/`else`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jsonSchema attribute conditionally required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required)

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers I already linked to your excellent answer on that other question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this question already has an awesome generic answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38781027/5127499).

That being said, you might be able to improve your data structure in regards to the `"DayActivity"`, which would also make it easier to formulate the corresponding JSON Schema.

---

Your `"DayActivity"` is currently an array of objects, with each object containing up to three properties at the same time: `"PhysicalActivity"`/`"StudyActivity"`/`"ArtActivity"`. How about something like the following instead, that only allows one of the three properties to be present in a single array item:

```
"DayActivity": {
  "type": "array",
  "minItems": 1,
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "properties": {
          "PhysicalActivity": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["Walking", "Running"]
          }
        },
        "required": ["PhysicalActivity"]
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "StudyActivity": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["Maths Class", "Science Class"]
          }
        },
        "required": ["StudyActivity"]
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "ArtActivity": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["Drawing", "Dance"]
          }
        },
        "required": ["ArtActivity"]
      }
    ]
  },
  "contains": {
    "required": ["PhysicalActivity"]
  }
}
```

Note the `"contains"` keyword in the end to ensure that there always needs to be at least one `"PhysicalActivity"` entry in the `"DayActivity"` array.

If you now want to conditionally enforce a `"StudyActivity"` on each weekday but `"SUNDAY"`, you could add the following inside the main schema (i.e. at the top level, where `"properties": { "DayHeader": ... }` is being declared:

```
"oneOf": [
  {
    "properties": {
      "DayHeader": {
        "properties": {
          "Day": {
            "const": "SUNDAY"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "properties": {
      "DayHeader": {
        "properties": {
          "Day": {
            "enum": [
              "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "ActivityDetail": {
        "properties": {
          "DayActivity": {
            "contains": {
              "required": ["StudyActivity"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

---

A complete schema could look something like this then:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["DayHeader", "ActivityDetail"],
  "properties": {
    "DayHeader": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Day": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "SUNDAY",
            "MONDAY",
            "TUESDAY",
            "WEDNESDAY",
            "THURSDAY",
            "FRIDAY",
            "SATURDAY"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "Day"
      ]
    },
    "ActivityDetail": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["DayActivity"],
      "properties": {
        "DayActivity": {
          "type": "array",
          "minItems": 1,
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "properties": {
                  "PhysicalActivity": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["Walking", "Running"]
                  }
                },
                "required": ["PhysicalActivity"]
              },
              {
                "properties": {
                  "StudyActivity": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["Maths Class", "Science Class"]
                  }
                },
                "required": ["StudyActivity"]
              },
              {
                "properties": {
                  "ArtActivity": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["Drawing", "Dance"]
                  }
                },
                "required": ["ArtActivity"]
              }
            ]
          },
          "contains": {
            "required": ["PhysicalActivity"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "DayHeader": {
          "properties": {
            "Day": {
              "const": "SUNDAY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "DayHeader": {
          "properties": {
            "Day": {
              "enum": [
                "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "ActivityDetail": {
          "properties": {
            "DayActivity": {
              "contains": {
                "required": ["StudyActivity"]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

The above successfully validates against:

```
{
  "DayHeader": { "Day": "SUNDAY"},
  "ActivityDetail": {
    "DayActivity": [
      { "PhysicalActivity": "Walking" }
    ]
  }
}
```

But not against the following (because a `"StudyActivity"` is missing:

```
{
  "DayHeader": { "Day": "WEDNESDAY"},
  "ActivityDetail": {
    "DayActivity": [
      { "PhysicalActivity": "Walking" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check this. Right now, I'm using "https://json-schema-faker.js.org/" by inputting the JSON schema and generating the output and found thay it is not generating correctly. Looks like I need to build a JSON schema validator class and passing the json & schema to validate. I will check on this. if possible, let me know how you are validating it.

Comment: Thank you. I converted to IF-else structure since I had to add conditions based on the Day header and for many more attributes such as DayActivity is one of the example listed here. I thought of having if-else inside 'DayActivity' would be more easier to understand the schema. I rebuilt it with if-else. Please find my updated one. If I change the DayHeader, it is not validating DayActivity based on the DayHeader.

Comment: @Sahank I meant adding your changed schema at the bottom of your question – not to my answer. I had a look at your suggested edit though. You changed the wrong `oneOf`. For these `if`/`then` clauses, you should focus on the `oneOf` at the top-level schema (the one at the bottom of my example here in the answer).